# using fflush on C++

Tags: c++, input, interactive, fflush

Can someone help me using `fflush` in C++

Here is a sample code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int a,b,i;
char result[20];

int main() {
  scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    printf("5\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(result);
    if (strcmp(result, "congratulation") == 0) break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is program for getting interactive input.

I usually use `cin` and `cout` so is it possible not using `printf` and `scanf`?

Comment: [That won't compile (`hasil` is not declared anywhere). It's not C either (`C` has no namespaces, and no iostream header).]

Comment: I usually use `cin` and `cout` so is it possible not using `printf` and `scanf`? Yes it's possible, use `cin` and `cout` (as usual) and not `printf` and `scanf`!

Comment: Are you asking how to flush when using cin and cout?

Comment: yes. i'm doing some research and fflush(stdout) is the same with cout<<flush on C++ but still need code example.

Comment: @zeulb You already got two fine C++ code examples, although the `<< flush` there is hidden in the `<< endl`, which actually does nothing more than `<< '\n' << flush`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation to C++ programming *style* is this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main() {
  string line;
  int a, b;

  if (cin >> a >> b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      cout << "5" << std::endl; // endl does the flushing
      if (std::getline(cin, line)) {
        if (line == "congratulations") {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that I deliberately added some error checking.

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't completely understood your question, the C++ version of your program would be something like this (assuming `hasil` should be `result`):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a,b,i;
    std::string result;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        std::cout << "5" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> result;
        if (result == "congratulation") break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that `std::endl` is equivalent to `'\n' << std::flush` and therefore both puts the line end and calls `.flush()` on the stream (which is your `fflush` equivalent).

Actually to get the real equivalent to your `scanf` call (and not press enter between a and b), you would have to do something like:

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::string line;
std::cin >> line;
std::istringstream str(line);
str >> a >> b;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have need for C IO facilities, include [`<cstdio>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/). You now have `std::printf` and `std::fflush` etc. You might consider calling [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/) if you want to use C IO and iostreams interwovenly.